# Rename/revalue values within a variable

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this and want to create the "Funding" Variable

```
ID   FundingSource    Funding   
1     asdf              Yes
2      NA               No
3     ljsdf             Yes
4      NA               No
```

I want to recode it such that all NA values are automatically coded as No and everything else (with some non-NA value) is coded as Yes since there are so many different Funding Source names. Here's some code I have so far that doesn't work:

```
 df %>% 
  if (FundingSource == "NA") {print(Funding == "No")}
else if (FundingSource =/= "NA") {print(Funding =="Yes")}

if("NA" %in% df$FundingSource) {print("No")} else if {print("Yes")}
```

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% mutate(Funding = ifelse(is.na(FundingSource), NA, FundingSource)`?

Comment: `df$Funding <- ifelse(is.na(df$FundingSource), "No", "Yes")`. But don't use `df` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here.

One nice trick of a `tibble` is you can calculate new columns on the fly as you build it.

Alternatively you could use `dplyr::mutate()` and either use `base::ifelse()` or `dplyr::if_else()` or `dplyr::case_when()` which is overkill here but useful if you have more than 2 conditions.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# calculate directly as you build tibble
tibble(ID = 1:4,
       FundingSource = c("asdf", NA, "ljsdf", NA),
       Funding = ifelse(!is.na(FundingSource), "Yes", "No"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>      ID FundingSource Funding
#>   <int> <chr>         <chr>  
#> 1     1 asdf          Yes    
#> 2     2 <NA>          No     
#> 3     3 ljsdf         Yes    
#> 4     4 <NA>          No


# perform mutate based on column with ifelse
# using base::ifelse, but dplyr::if_else works fine here too
tibble(ID = 1:4,
       FundingSource = c("asdf", NA, "ljsdf", NA)) %>% 
  mutate(Funding = ifelse(!is.na(FundingSource), "Yes", "No"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>      ID FundingSource Funding
#>   <int> <chr>         <chr>  
#> 1     1 asdf          Yes    
#> 2     2 <NA>          No     
#> 3     3 ljsdf         Yes    
#> 4     4 <NA>          No

# perform mutate based on column with dplyr::case_when
# useful if more than 2 conditions
tibble(ID = 1:4,
       FundingSource = c("asdf", NA, "ljsdf", NA)) %>% 
  mutate(Funding = case_when(
    !is.na(FundingSource) ~ "Yes",
    TRUE ~ "No"
  ))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>      ID FundingSource Funding
#>   <int> <chr>         <chr>  
#> 1     1 asdf          Yes    
#> 2     2 <NA>          No     
#> 3     3 ljsdf         Yes    
#> 4     4 <NA>          No
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>